# Print ssh lines as soon as they arrive with python - asyncssh

Tags: python, ssh, python-asyncio

When using asyncssh, i would like to print the  outputs line as soon as they arrive. In the example, it wait for the command to completer

```
import asyncio, asyncssh, sys
@asyncio.coroutine
def run_client():
    with (yield from asyncssh.connect('localhost')) as conn:
        stdin, stdout, stderr = yield from conn.open_session('echo hello1; sleep 5 ; echo hello2')

        output = yield from stdout.read()
        print(output, end='')

        yield from stdout.channel.wait_closed()

        status = stdout.channel.get_exit_status()
        if status:
            print('Program exited with status %d' % status, file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            print('Program exited successfully')

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run_client())
```

i tried to modify the "yield from stdout.read" line (iterate on it, ...), but nothing works.

Comment: You probably need to flush stdout.

Comment: no, that's a asyncio problem, not just a flush problem.

Comment: Use [stdout.readline()](http://asyncssh.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api.html#asyncssh.SSHReader.readline).

Answer (score 1):

As Vincent said, i used readline:

```
output="debut"
while output:
    output=yield from stdout.readline()
    print(output)
```

it works... I'm just not realy confortable with this `yield from` thing.

Comment: If you are able to use python3.5, then you can use the `async` and `await` keywords. So your function definition becomes `async def run_client()` and your `yield from` turns into `await`.